# How to search for items inside a nested list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So i am trying to get only the searched items with a hierarchy using the input box at the top of the page.

My current code only shows the main list items in the parent list.

Current Results:

[image]

Desired Results:

[image]

```js
$("#searchInputField").on("input", function() {
  var searchTerms = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(".nav_links li").each(function() {
    var hasMatch = searchTerms.length == 0 || $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms) > 0;
    var listItem = $(this);
    listItem.toggle(hasMatch);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<form action="#" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input id="searchInputField" type="search" placeholder="Find" autocomplete="off">
</form>
<ul class="nav_links">
  <li>
    <span class="link_name navItem">Home</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span class="link_name navItem">Costing Logistics</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><span class="navItem">HTML & CSS</span></li>
      <li><span class="navItem">JavaScript</span></li>
      <li><span class="navItem">PHP & MySQL</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/abdotamer3/j7tdo18y/5/

Comment: Thx for the addition that would make it more responsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your javascript. `indexOf()` returns the *position* of the search term in your text, so when you write `indexOf(searchTerms) > 0`, you're asking for all list items where the search term is present *at the second character or later*. This is easily confirmed - search for "TML" or "vascript" and you'll get results.

Change it to

```
var hasMatch = searchTerms.length == 0 || $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms) >= 0;
```

and your code should work again.

(Basically, change `> 0` to `>= 0`. Or you can change it to `!= -1` and get the same result.)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the issue that `-1` is returned when a match is missing using `.indexOf()`
Here's a better way that makes use of

- the equally performant and [more readable `.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)
- toggle a Utility CSS class instead of defining CSS states in JS
- PS: don't forget to `.trim()` your strings!

```js
const $search = $("#searchInputField")
const $li = $(".nav_links > li");

const filterList = () => {
  const val = $.trim($search.val()).toLowerCase();
  
  $li.each((i, el) => {
    const text = $.trim($(el).text()).toLowerCase();
    $(el).toggleClass("u-none", !text.includes(val))
  });
}

$search.on("input", filterList);
```

```css
/* UTILITY CLASSES */

.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<form action="#" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input id="searchInputField" type="search" placeholder="Find" autocomplete="off">
</form>
<ul class="nav_links">
  <li>
    <span class="link_name navItem">Home</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span class="link_name navItem">Costing Logistics</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><span class="navItem">HTML & CSS</span></li>
      <li><span class="navItem">JavaScript</span></li>
      <li><span class="navItem">PHP & MySQL</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And why jQuery if in pure **JavaScript** can be done like:

```js
const EL_search = document.querySelector("#searchInputField");
const ELS_li = document.querySelectorAll(".nav_links > li");

const filterList = () => {
  const val = EL_search.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  
  ELS_li.forEach(EL => {
    const text = EL.textContent.trim().toLowerCase();
    EL.classList.toggle("u-none", !text.includes(val));
  });
}

EL_search.addEventListener("input", filterList);
```

```css
/* UTILITY CLASSES */

.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input id="searchInputField" type="search" placeholder="Find" autocomplete="off">
</form>
<ul class="nav_links">
  <li>
    <span class="link_name navItem">Home</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span class="link_name navItem">Costing Logistics</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><span class="navItem">HTML & CSS</span></li>
      <li><span class="navItem">JavaScript</span></li>
      <li><span class="navItem">PHP & MySQL</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```